# Optional image input field's kicking me out of session

Tags: django

This problem has been puzzling me for few hours now. I'm designing an
update profile page where user can update photo if user wishes.

The problem is that when I leave the image input field blank and edit other fields and hit submit, nothing is changed and I get kicked out of session, on the other hand when I select an image to upload and hit submit everything is updated and function runs as I designed it.

Here's relevant code:

```
class User(models.Model):
    photo  = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True)
```

It's a Charfield 'coz I store only reference to the image in database.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name='photo' class="form-control">
```

View:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

     photo = request.FILES['photo']
     if photo:
         fs = FileSystemStorage()
         filename = fs.save(photo.name, photo)
         uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
         if uploaded_file_url[-4:] not in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS:
               error = 'Invalid File Type'
               errors.append(error)

     print(uploaded_file_url)
```

You can ignore the print statement. I spread bunch of those all over the this function so I can see how the function works at each stage. Thanks to this I was able to determine that when the file input field is left blank other code is no longer being processed and program exits out. But clearly the field is supposedly optional. I checked the indentation too. Making my head in.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

As turns out I broke the function execution by not initialising the `uploaded_file_url` variable. I tried to change `request.FILES['photo']` to `request.FILES.get('photo')` which does behave slightly different but the difference in behaviour isn't obvious at all. To cut this short when I used the `.get('photo')` it raised an error in browser which hinted me what's been wrong all that time. Initialise the variable is all I had to do.

The main difference I observed was that `request.FILES['xxx']` won't raise an error if there's something off about the code, it will exit out without a word whereas `request.get('xxx')` will raise an error.